# Do the Ordinatus Siege Engines reappear in the Horus Heresy

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

In the book Fallen Angel, lion El Johnson gives Pertuarbo 3 Ordinatus Siege Engines telling him to put them to good use at Isstvan.

Have these reappeared yet later in the series, have we seen the Iron Warriors use them at all?

Comment: Probably not: While Titans and tankls are in use for millennia, most ordinati are single-campaign weapons, too heavy, cumbersome and too prone to damage to transport them. In most cases, they are sort of improvised weapon built from the usable junk - i.e. engines of a destroyed frigate.

Comment: I’m sure it’s stated somewhere (possibly in fallen angels itself) that Horus needs them as they’re the only engines powerful enough to break the gates on terra. That’s where we’ll probably see them, at the final siege

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's mentioned again briefly in book 20 "The Primarchs" at the start of the short story "The Lion".

Lion El'Johnson appears much less trustful than before and it's mentioned:

> Trust had been a scarce commodity for the Lion before Horus's betrayal and even then he had been taken for a fool. Perturabo had used his status as a brother to trick the Lion, taking control of the devastating war engines of Diamat under the guise of alliance, only to turn those weapons against the servants of the Emperor. The shame of being so manipulated gnawed at the Lion's conscience and he would never again accept the simple word of his brothers.

They then appear again in book 35, "Eye of Terra" in the short story "Ironfire".

> Before him was [Eradicant](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Eradicant_and_Obliteratus), the mountainous centerpiece of the Iron Warriors encampment. Stolen from the mechanicum on Diamat by the 1st Legion. The guargantuan mobile artillery piece had subsequently been entrusted to Perturabo before the drop site massacre.